# Jquery wont run, how to check for errors?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to get a responsive navigation to work. I had a tutorial I followed and I did all the same things as he did, however I cannot get it to work.

I have tested with other jquery scripts to see that the jquery.min.js is loaded and working.

```
const navSlide = () => {
    const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
    const nav = document.querySelector('nav-links');

    burger.addEventListener('click', () => {
        nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');
    });

navSlide();
```

It just wont make it slide the navigation. Is there something I did wrong?(obv is must be)

Comment: Is `nav-links` a class or id? `nav-link` isn't an html tag, so that might be an issue

Comment: I made this https://codepen.io/ChrisarN/pen/GbJmdL of the whole thing. I just cannot get it working. Been at it for hours.

Comment: Could you explain how you want the page to change when the nav links are interacted with?

Answer (score 0):

Try this --

```
const navSlide = () => {
    const burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
    const nav = document.querySelector('.nav-links');

    burger.addEventListener('click', () => {
        nav.classList.toggle('nav-active');
    });

navSlide();
```

I think you may have missed the `.` in your query selector.

Comment: Good catch! Been looking at the code for hours, dident see it. However it dident fix my problem. I made an codepen of it. https://codepen.io/ChrisarN/pen/GbJmdL